# Multilple single-use widgets with the same output callback

Tags: widgets

I have this scenario where I need to provide various single-use widgets.

They're all displayed the same way, so I don't feel the need for a different display functions for each widget. However, if I use the same callback on all [`wp_register_sidebar_widget`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_sidebar_widget/) instances, only the last one is active.

I'm forced to have multiple identical functions, differing only the name. How can I improve it?

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_single_use_widgets' );
function register_single_use_widgets() {

  $id = 'first';
  $name = 'First Widget';
  $widget_ops = array( 'description' => 'This is the first widget.' );
  wp_register_sidebar_widget( $id, $name, 'single_widget_display', $widget_ops );

  $id = 'second';
  $name = 'Second Widget';
  $widget_ops = array( 'description' => 'This is the second widget.' );
  wp_register_sidebar_widget( $id, $name, 'single_widget_display2', $widget_ops );

  $id = 'third';
  $name = 'Third Widget';
  $widget_ops = array( 'description' => 'This is the third widget.' );
  wp_register_sidebar_widget( $id, $name, 'single_widget_display3', $widget_ops );

}

function single_widget_display( $args ) {
  $name = $args['widget_name'];
  echo "<p> $name </p>";
}

function single_widget_display2( $args ) {
  $name = $args['widget_name'];
  echo "<p> $name </p>";
}

function single_widget_display3( $args ) {
  $name = $args['widget_name'];
  echo "<p> $name </p>";
}
```

Comment: `wp_register_sidebar_widget` is a very old function, and not how normal widgets are registered, where are your classes implementing `WP_Widget`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `wp_register_sidebar_widget` is a very outdated function from early implementations of widgets. Apparently back then widgets could only be used once each and the output callback name seems to be what made a widget unique, despite the existence of an ID. The single-use nature of these widgets doesn't appear to be an intentional feature.

Given it's age I would suggest using the newer API, based on `register_widget()`. To register 3 widgets with the same output you would create a class for the widget, with some additionaland register 3 different instances of it.

```
function wpse_292985_widget_display( $args ) {
    echo '<p>' . $args['widget_name'] . '</p>';
}

class WPSE_292985_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct( $id, $name, $widget_ops ) {
        parent::__construct( $id, $name, $widget_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        wpse_292985_widget_display( $args );
    }
}

function wpse_292985_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( new WPSE_292985_Widget( 
        'first', 
        'First Widget', 
        ['description' => 'This is the first widget.']
    ) );

    register_widget( new WPSE_292985_Widget( 
        'second', 
        'Second Widget', 
        ['description' => 'This is the second widget.']
    ) );

    register_widget( new WPSE_292985_Widget( 
        'third', 
        'Third Widget', 
        ['description' => 'This is the third widget.']
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse_292985_register_widgets' );
```

The first thing happening there is defining the function we want the widget to output. It accepts `$args` as an argument which we'll pass through in our widget class.

The next bit is the class for the Widget. This class is just a copy of the generic WordPress widget class, but we're setting the `widget()` method here to output our function.

Then we register 3 widgets by creating new instances of our widget class and passing them into `register_widget()`.

Comment: "The single-use nature of these widgets doesn't appear to be an intentional feature": Yeah, I know. But that's exactly what I need. Your code is much more up-to-date, saner, and I believe follows best practices, but... Doesn't produce widgets that can be used *only once*.